# “Google MC Funnels API” (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I set up one example of MC Funnels, and everything is OK !!:

- Downloaded Master from git.
- Put one account and it works!
- **And it is OK** ! Returns-me some results of book samples...

So, I put new code to get "mcf:" but receive " **401 Unauthorized** "

**QUESTION:** how/where to authorise queries for  "mcf:xxxxxxx" metrics and dimentions?

The code I used:

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "templates/base.php";
// $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
// $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books']);    //not sure here..

// $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
   $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);      //not sure here..

        $mcf = $service->data_mcf(
            'ga:80456636',
            '2015-02-22',
            '2015-02-23',
            'mcf:totalConversionValue',
            array(
                'dimensions' => 'mcf:source,mcf:medium'
            )
        );

        echo"<pre>";
        var_dump($mcf);
        echo"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you commented out all of the code for $client.  Google books is a public api which means you can use a public API key to authenticate.  Google Analytics data is private data which means you need to either use Oauth2 or a service account.

**Service account Example**

```
   require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
   session_start();     
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.       web root.

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
    $client_id = '[Your client id]';
    $Email_address = '[YOur Service account email address Address]';     
    $key_file_location = '[Locatkon of key file]';      

    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

    // seproate additional scopes with a comma   
    $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($Email_address,         
                             array($scopes),        
                             $key);     

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
         $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);      
    }       

    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$mcf = $service->data_mcf->get('ga:80456636',
            '2015-02-22',
            '2015-02-23',
            'mcf:totalConversionValue',
            array(
                'dimensions' => 'mcf:source,mcf:medium'
            )
        );

        echo"<pre>";
        var_dump($mcf);
        echo"</pre>";
```

Comment: Yes use the info you got from Google developer console.

Comment: One  missing class: **Fatal error: Class 'Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials' not found in ** ? Please, What is this?

Comment: you didnt download part of the client library probably my example uses the v1 master branch https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master not composer

Comment: OK!!  correct version works! Thanks! **but another error:** -> `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Analytics::data_mcf() in....'

Comment: you really should look at the client library code you can figure this out on your own  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php  $service->data_mcf->get()

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you o lot!